# Out Of Range Exception during get the data keys

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, gridview

Q:

I have a gridview ,and i try to delete some record , I store my primary keys in `DataKeyNames`.

my question has two parts :

1-The following code make an exception, I don't know the reason:

```
 protected void gv_courses_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                ICollection keys = gv_moreCourses.DataKeys[index].Values;
                //////the rest of the code.
            }

            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
            }

         }
```

my aspx:

```
 DataKeyNames="permission_code,lect_code,note_title,iscourse"

 <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/Symbols-Delete-icon.png"
                                                                                    CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' CommandName="deleteCourse" />
```

---

The exception is:in this line `gv_moreCourses.DataKeys[index];`

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

2- If i solve the first problem how to access each value in my `keys`.prefer `LINQ`.

Comment: That excepion is thrown in which you didn't complete. Make sure the casted index is in your specific range.

Comment: when i trace, i get the correct `index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in the `RowCommand` event for a GridView called `gv_courses`, you are taking the index and then referencing another GridView called `gv_moreCourses` to grab the key.  If `gv_courses` has more rows than `gv_moreCourses` (or `gv_moreCourses` doesn't have a defined key), then you will get an error from clicking on one of the latter row indexes that don't exist on the second Grid.  Did you intend for that to say this instead?

```
ICollection keys = gv_courses.DataKeys[index].Values;
                      ^^^^ remove "more"
```

**Edit**  The return type of `DataKeys.Values` is actually `System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary`, which contains an indexer and properties `.Keys` and `.Values` for easy access to the contents of the key:

```
IOrderedDictionary keys = gv_courses.DataKeys[index].Values;
^^^^ change ICollection to IOrderedDictionary

keys[0]  ...  // permission_code
keys[1]  ...  // lect_code
keys[2]  ...  // note_title
keys[3]  ...  // iscourse
```

Comment: Great , you solve my first problem, then How to get every key in my keys collection.LINQ.thanks a lot .

Comment: the second part of my question ,please.

Comment: this is the disadvantage of copy and paste , i write the code for my gridview `gv_moreCourses` and paste it forgetting to edit this line.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Index will have the value of the Selected Data Key, like it can have different value than `0`, Since it will require DataKey Index `gv_moreCourses.DataKeys[DataKey]`

You can directly get the value from `e.CommandArgument`. It will return the Selected Row Data key value

OR, you can get it by passing in the name of the DataKey Name, e.g. `gv_moreCourses.DataKeys["NameofDataKey"].Values;`

Comment: mmm, i get the index of the selected row from it, but i wanna to get the primary keys to delete from the database

Comment: e.CommandArgument will return what you are looking. Just debug it.

Comment: `int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); ` .doesn't make any problem, the problem in the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Does the error come on the line where you index the table? This seems to be an indexing bug. Are you giving the values of index from correct range? It can be that your other part of program starts indexes from 1 and this parts need them to start from 0.

This came to my mind at first view without looking more deeply to your problem.